# How to retrieve vegetation of a given location

Tags: android, location, geo

This seems like a completely useless information but i would like to know if there is some kind of mechanism which lets me get the approximate vegetation of a location.

I want to know if I am inside a City, or in a desert, or if I'm currently in the woods, or on the see.

Also is there a chance to get the nearest lake of sea?

This seems a bit of an odd question...and I hope you understand what I'm looking for.

Thank you very much

Comment: There might be, but not using the current Google Map APIs

Comment: For the forest, maybe you could try to extract color statistics from a map showing where you are. A simple test would be "If the green is the dominant color in the map around me, there is more chance that I am currently in a forest than in a city". If you manage to extract that information from a location, you could build a statistical approach to make your results more consistent.

Comment: how is this an android question?

Comment: I want to do this on a Android phone. @yumyum - that was an idea i tried to follow but i hopped there would be an elegant or even built in way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is difficult to do because of a lack of readily available data accessible from Android, but I think your best bet is to use a crowd-sourced dataset such as [OpenStreetMap (OSM)](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

You'd need to set up your own spatial database (e.g., [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/)) and import OSM data into the database.

OSM standardizes multiple vegetation label types, including:

- natural=bare_rock
- natural=fell
- natural=glacier
- landuse=grass
- natural=grassland
- natural=heath
- natural=mud
- natural=screen
- natural=sand
- natural=scrub
- natural=tree
- natural=wetland
- natural=wood.

See the [OSM - Natural - Land Cover wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Natural#Land_cover) for more detail on OSM labels of vegetation.

Then, you'd create a server-side API (hosted in a web server such as [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) or [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/)) to receive the mobile phone's current location, do a [spatial query via PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16414/point-in-polygon-algorithm-for-multiple-polygons) to determine the polygon and natural land cover type (i.e., vegetation) the phone's location lies within, and return the vegetation type to the phone.

Another option is to use ESRI shape files instead of OSM data, and load this data into the PostGIS database.

Comment: I ended up using this approach. Ty!